# Is it possible to change Enterprise Library logging listener setting programmatically?

Tags: .net, web-config, enterprise-library, app-config, exception-logging

I'm using Ent Lib 5, and I need to be able to update the databaseInstanceName property of Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.FormattedDatabaseTraceListener listener.

The databaseInstanceName is defined in my app.config, but I need to set it dynamically.

I've looked into using Fluent Configuration, but I didn't see a way to edit a listener.

Is there any way to change a listener's configuration at run time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just write to the configuration file programatically, the file is monitored by the EL and it *should* notice the change and start logging the the new location automatically.